# Join a selected field to a custom formatter with Play Framework

Tags: java, forms, playframework

i'm new with Play Framework and I want to checks my forms.

I currently try to create a custom formatter for Dates. When I receive a field called "startTimestamp", I want it to pass by my custom formatter which will transform it into a Java date.

This is my code :

```
public static Result create() {
    Formatters.register(Date.class, new Formatters.SimpleFormatter<Date>(){

        @Override
        public Date parse(String timestamp, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
            return new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
        }

        @Override
        public String print(Date arg0, Locale arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    });

    // controller code 
}
```

I don't understand how it could possibly work. How could i say to my formatter that a special String field called "startTimestamp" need to be formatted, but my others string fields don't need it ?

At the beginning I wanted to bind my object with some others objects but the bind method from play forms accepts only Strings. If there is a solution for this I could be interested too !

Am I clear ? I don't speak a very great english so it could be a little confuse for you ^^

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

this will work since play know to convert between a map and an object that have the same attribute names

in addition you on your template you specify the Object that is mapped to this form 
using the two together is enough for play to infer the type of the field being converted

you can't bind other type then string because the conversion is done between the Web Page (Http format) and the Java Language. Http doesn't have object only strings

I don't speak a very great English either

you could register the formatter on the Global.Onstart